# Compare three cells and the output is different pending on the answers in three cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I am trying to put this together and all I can find is not helping me.  I want to do the following:

- If A2, B2, or C2 have Yes and D2 has Yes, than Match
- If A2, B2, and C2 have No and D2 has No, than Match
- if anything else, No Match

I currently have it as:

```
=IF(and(A2=B2,B2=C2,C2=D2),"Match","No Match")
```

However, I need one to be an OR statement for Yes answers, and the above formula works only for the No answers.  Is there  way around this so that it is in one formula?

I'm using Office 2016 in Windows 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If at least one of `A2`, `B2` or `C2` must be "yes" when `D2` is "yes", then try:
    =IF(OR(COUNTIF(A2:D2,"no")=4,AND(COUNTIF(A2:C2,"yes")>0,D2="yes")),"match","nomatch")

The `COUNTIF` function will count the number of occurrences matching a certain condition.

If we want all four cells to be "no", then the count of cells whose value is "no" must be 4, hence `COUNTIF(A2:D2,"no")=4`.

If `D2` = "yes", then we want at least one of the other cells to also be "yes", hence `(COUNTIF(A2:C2,"yes")>0`.

Comment: This helped solve my problem.  Just so I understand,  why is there a >4 and >0 in the formula?  What is the purpose?

Comment: Correction to my last comment: =4

Comment: See the edit to my answer